# Incompatible object type when create and alter a table value function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-function, create-function

I'm getting the below error for the given function.

Msg 2010, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetTableFromDelimitedValues, Line 2
Cannot perform alter on 'dbo.GetTableFromDelimitedValues' because it is an incompatible object type.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects 
              WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('[GetTableFromDelimitedValues]'))
BEGIN
   EXECUTE('CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTableFromDelimitedValues](@input varchar(max),
       @delimiter char(1) = ",")) RETURNS @Result TABLE (
       Value nvarchar(4000)) AS BEGIN RETURN END')
END
GO


ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTableFromDelimitedValues](
       @input varchar(max),
       @delimiter char(1) = ',')
RETURNS @Result TABLE
(
       Value nvarchar(4000)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @position int;
    DECLARE @column nvarchar(4000);

    WHILE LEN(@input) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @position = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @input);
        IF (@position < 0) OR (@position IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            SET @position = 0;
        END

        IF @position > 0 
        BEGIN
            SET @column = SUBSTRING(@input, 1, @position - 1);
            SET @input = SUBSTRING(@input, @position + 1, LEN(@input) - @position)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @column = @input;
            SET @input = '';
        END 

        INSERT @Result (Value) 
        SELECT @column;
    END;

    RETURN;                
END
GO
```

Can someone please help me to get the compatible type by fixing the function?

Comment: Did one of the answers below solve this issue?

Answer (score 37):

You need to **DROP** and **CREATE** the function in this particular context

Since there is change in function return type, we must drop then recreate the function.

There are three types of functions,

- **Scalar**
- **Inline table valued** and
- **Multi Statement**

ALTER cannot be used to change the function type.

Answer (score 5):

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT [name] FROM sys.objects 
            WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('GetTableFromDelimitedValues'))
BEGIN
   DROP FUNCTION [GetTableFromDelimitedValues];
END
GO

/*  Now create function */
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTableFromDelimitedValues](
       @input varchar(max),
       @delimiter char(1) = ',')
RETURNS @Result TABLE (
       Value nvarchar(4000)
)
AS
BEGIN
..
..
..
RETURN;
END
```

in `OBJECT_ID` function you need to pass only function name not the schema. and why would create it 1st and then `Alter` it . Just check for existence 1st if it exists then drop function and create your function as I have shown above.

Also do not add `Type` in where clause when checking for existence, if there is another object not a function but any other object with the same name, it will not pick it up in your select statement and you will end up creating a function with a name an object already exists (this will throw an error).

IF you want to do it your way this is how you would go about it

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects 
              WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('[GetTableFromDelimitedValues]'))
BEGIN
   EXECUTE('CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTableFromDelimitedValues]() RETURNS @Result TABLE (
       Value nvarchar(4000)) AS BEGIN RETURN END')
END
GO
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 

Initially I approached the problem in the same way as you suggested (Drop|Create) but it didn't go through as - Problem with DROP, could be some times executing user may not have rights to DROP in prod environments, hence to be on the safer side should go with ALTER.

Comment: @ary have a look now I have updated my answer to fix the issue you had in your actual query.

Comment: Thank you for your continued help.
Sorry it didn't work and continued to show the same error.
Cannot perform alter on 'dbo.GetTableFromDelimitedValues' because it is an incompatible object type.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, this happened when I have a table name exactly as proc name. so making a change to proc name or a table referred in the proc should also fix this error message.

Answer (score 0):

I have something to notify on your error related to your code: 
The error says `Cannot perform alter on 'dbo.GetTableFromDelimitedValues' because it is an incompatible object type`
Which means that you have to look on your lines after the `ALTER....`
And yes there t is: 
`@input varchar(max)`
The SQL server 2008 r2 not accept objects `varchar(MAX)`, but that is only if you run a stored procedure
Because if you create a table by hand then it is fully accept it.
If you want a large cell then type `varchar(1024)` or `varchar(2048)` both of them are accepted. I face this issue few days ago...
That is my humble opinion

**ADDITIONAL CHANGES**
Use this

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('[GetTableFromDelimitedValues]')) 
BEGIN 
execute('CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTableFromDelimitedValues]( @input varchar(max), @delimiter char(1)= ",") RETURNS @Result TABLE ( Value nvarchar(4000)) AS BEGIN RETURN END')
END GO
```

.... Pay attention to the change from ' to the "

** ADDITIONAL CHANGES **

I use the following which also works fine... with no any issue...

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT [name] FROM sys.objects 
            WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('GetTableFromDelimitedValues'))
BEGIN
   DROP FUNCTION [GetTableFromDelimitedValues];
END
BEGIN
   execute('CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTableFromDelimitedValues]() 
    RETURNS 
    @Result TABLE (
    Value nvarchar(4000)) 
    AS 
    BEGIN 
    RETURN 
    END')
    execute('ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTableFromDelimitedValues](
       @input varchar(max),
       @delimiter char(1) = ",")
       RETURNS @Result TABLE (
       Value nvarchar(4000))
       AS 
    BEGIN 
    RETURN 
    END')
END
GO
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Sorry it didn't work and continued to show the same error after removing max with 1024.

Comment: Try to see if the `@delimiter char(1) = ',')` syntax is the proper one... In any case the issue comes from this area.

Comment: that works fine for me... `IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects 
              WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('[GetTableFromDelimitedValues]'))
BEGIN
   execute('CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTableFromDelimitedValues](
       @input varchar(max), @delimiter char(1)= ",")       
RETURNS @Result TABLE (
       Value nvarchar(4000)) AS BEGIN RETURN END')
END
GO`  .... Pay attention to the change from `' ` to the `"`

Comment: The execute for CREATE FUNCTION within IF NOT EXISTS block works fine, but I'm getting issue on the the followed ALTER FUNCTION where it says - Cannot perform *alter* on 'dbo.GetTableFromDelimitedValues' because it is an incompatible object type.

Comment: Hi<
I have updated the original question with the complete code, the function will return a table values output for a coma delimited input.

The IF block (where the EXECUTE for CREATE FUNCTION is written) works fine if I ran upto the end of IF block. This ensures the syntax is correct.

But when I ran the complete script, it fails at ALTER FUNCTION saying Cannot perform alter on 'dbo.GetTableFromDelimitedValues' because it is an incompatible object type.

Comment: hank you for your reply. @M.Ali also suggested the same. Initially I approached the problem in the same way (Drop|Create) but it didn't go through as - Problem with DROP, could be some times executing user may not have rights to DROP in prod environments, hence to be on the safer side should go with ALTER.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46290/discussion-between-lefteris-gkinis-and-ary)

Answer (score 0):

I confirm the below code works. Seems the issue was somehow a scalar value function created with the same name during my development and got error as script's multi part table value alter statement function is compatible with it.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects 
              WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('[GetTableFromDelimitedValues]'))
BEGIN
   EXEC sp_executesql 
    @statement = N'CREATE FUNCTION dbo.[GetTableFromDelimitedValues] () RETURNS @Result 
    TABLE(Value nvarchar(4000))
    AS 
    BEGIN 
      RETURN 
    END' ;
END
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTableFromDelimitedValues](
    @input varchar(max),
    @delimiter char(1) = ',')
RETURNS @Result TABLE
(
    Value nvarchar(4000)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @position int;
    DECLARE @column nvarchar(4000);

    WHILE LEN(@input) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @position = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @input);
        IF (@position < 0) OR (@position IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            SET @position = 0;
        END

        IF @position > 0 
        BEGIN
            SET @column = SUBSTRING(@input, 1, @position - 1);
            SET @input = SUBSTRING(@input, @position + 1, LEN(@input) - @position)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @column = @input;
            SET @input = '';
        END 

        INSERT @Result (Value) 
        SELECT @column;
    END;

    RETURN;                
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- bug does function created and data return is not field define, just change after the table(add field) returns.
- solution fix bug:

- deleted function just
- edit key word "Alter" => "Create"
- F5 is created function is success

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't include code as image. Prefer copy/paste